# Hamiltonian function

Tags: control-engineering

I have some difficulties to understand the certain part here. The part which is shown with λp
velocity and λv
control input is not clear to me. As we already have constraints for velocity and control input, I do not understand the main concept behind these two terms. They have been shown as co-state components, but they are still unclear.

Note: It is from the academic article named "Conditions to Provable System-Wide Optimal Coordination of Connected and Automated Vehicles".

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]